# What means a then() returned inside a recursive promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I have the following code:

```
function someAsyncOperation(){
    const myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
    return Promise.resolve(myArray);
    // return Promise.reject("Reject from someAsyncOperation");
}

const random = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}

const myFunction = (item) => {
    return someAsyncOperation() // this function returns an array
    .then((array) => {
        if(!array.includes(item)){
            console.log(`The element ${item} has NOT been found inside the array`);
            return myFunction(random()).then((r) => console.log(`Hello World ${r}`));
        }
        else{
            console.log(`The element ${item} has been found inside the array`);
            return item;
        }
    });
}

myFunction(random()).then(res => {
    // success
    console.log("Success", res);
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here which could be either your custom error
    // or an error from someAsyncOperation()
    console.log("Error", err);
});
```

And here are some examples of it's result:

> **1st example of an answer**

```
The element 10 has NOT been found inside the array
The element 8 has NOT been found inside the array
The element 7 has NOT been found inside the array
The element 5 has been found inside the array
Hello World 5
Hello World undefined
Hello World undefined
Success undefined
```

> **2nd example of an answer**

```
The element 9 has NOT been found inside the array
Nuevo elemento random generado 10
The element 10 has NOT been found inside the array
Nuevo elemento random generado 3
The element 3 has been found inside the array
Hello World 3
Hello World undefined
Success undefined
```

> **3rd example of an answer**

```
The element 5 has been found inside the array
Success 5
```

---

**So, my question is:**

Why outputs `Hello World undefined` and `Success undefined` sometimes? I mean exactly: what is doing that `then` in `return myFunction(random()).then((r) => console.log(Hello World ${r}));` ???

---

**EDIT:**

Exaclty, I expect to have in the `return r` (*JaromandaX's answer below*) not only the ***found result***, but also the history of the ***not founds results*** in the order they appeared. Here an example of what I need:

```
The element 10 has NOT been found inside the array
The element 8 has NOT been found inside the array
The element 7 has NOT been found inside the array
The element 5 has been found inside the array
Hello World 10
Hello World 8
Hello World 7
Success 5
```

Answer (score 3):

The code

```
return myFunction(random()).then((r) => console.log(`Hello World ${r}`))
```

will return a promise that resolves to the value returned in the last `.then` (i.e. you have a promise chain, and the resolved value is the result of the chain)

In this case, this value is `undefined` as that what console.log returns

you probably want to return a value, so

```
return myFunction(random()).then((r) => (console.log(`Hello World ${r}`), r))
```

or

```
return myFunction(random()).then((r) => {
    console.log(`Hello World ${r}`); 
    return r;
})
```

Putting that into your code, we get

```js
function someAsyncOperation(){
    const myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
    return Promise.resolve(myArray);
    // return Promise.reject("Reject from someAsyncOperation");
}

const random = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}

const myFunction = (item) => {
    return someAsyncOperation() // this function returns an array
    .then((array) => {
        if(!array.includes(item)){
            console.log(`The element ${item} has NOT been found inside the array`);
            return myFunction(random()).then((r) => {
                console.log(`Hello World ${r}`);
                return r;
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log(`The element ${item} has been found inside the array`);
            return item;
        }
    });
}

myFunction(random()).then(res => {
    // success
    console.log("Success", res);
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here which could be either your custom error
    // or an error from someAsyncOperation()
    console.log("Error", err);
});
```

Comment: _i.e._ If the last element found was `4`, why your code returns `Hello World 4` in the others `then` when an element was not found ??? I mean, why did not returns _i.e_ `Hello World 6` `Hello World 8` supossing that `6` and  `8` were the elements not found ??

Comment: @robe007 - what output do you expect?

Comment: I have edited the post to show you what is the output I expect. If you can take a look, would be helpful !